# Strip down SVG to one part of it

Tags: image, svg, image-processing

I am not very familiar with SVG and was hoping I can filter out a part of an existing SVG. I have the following SVG

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1223" height="331" viewBox="-2 47 1223 331">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="a">
      <path d="M84.5 208.2c77.3-15 161.7-47.3 237.1-70.1C529.6 81.8 747.8 29.3 962.2 6.4c34-3 72.4-4.4 104.2 9.8 26 11.3 55.5 31.9 80.4 45.2 15.2 8.3 36.4 17.8 47.7 31.6 22 24.8 33.4 63.8 19.7 95.2-44.8 77.5-174.6 122.4-256.8 149.3-86.8 19-180.7 22.3-269.3 22-157.6-3-324.7-17.4-481.4-33.2-28.6-2.3-63-2.1-91.7-.1-19.7.9-54.5 6.2-74.3 3.3l-4.2-1.1c-3.3-1.5-9.7-5.8-12.7-8l-5.5-5.5C1.9 293.5 2 263.4 8.3 238.3l2.5-5 3.6-4.1 4.7-3c20-8.7 44.1-13.8 65.4-18z" />
    </clipPath>
    <pattern id="b" width="39.37" height="39.37" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <path fill="#71CE01" d="M0 0h100v100H0z" />
      <path fill="#359200" opacity=".15" d="M0 0h50v100H0z" />
      <path fill="#359200" opacity=".15" d="M0 0h100v50H0z" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="rotate(366.63 612 182)">
    <path d="M-62-492l1348 0 0 1348-1348 0z" fill="#358806" />
    <path d="M1050 142.3a39 39 0 00-9.7-25.3c-1.5-1.6-3.3-3-5.2-4.4-1.9-1.4-4-2.5-6.1-3.4-7.2-3.3-15.3-3.4-23-2.4-7.4.9-14.6 2.5-21.7 4.7-7 2.4-13.8 5.1-20.8 7.4-4 1.3-7.9 2.8-12 3.4-8.7 1.6-17.6.3-26.2-1.6-5.4-1.2-11-2.6-16.6-3-4.7-.5-9.4 0-14.1.1-7.2.2-14.3 1.2-21.5 2-4.9.4-9.8 1.4-14.7 2-5.6.7-11.3 1-17 2-12.4 2.4-24 7.8-36 12-5.2 2-10.4 3.9-15.5 6-5.6 2.3-11.1 4.6-16.8 6.5-7.8 2.5-15.3 5.8-23.2 7.7-5.3 1.4-10.8 2-16.2 2.8-3 .4-6 1-9 1.3-4 .3-8 .4-11.8.5-9 0-18 .4-26.8-1-8.8-1-17.6-2.3-26.4-3.3-3.8-.4-7.7-.8-11.5-1.1-4.7-.3-9.4-.5-14-.6-6.6 0-13 .6-19.6 1.2-6.8.3-13.6 1.7-20.2 3.5-3.5 1-7 2-10.5 3.1-4 1.2-7.8 2.6-11.3 4.7a34 34 0 00-5.3 3.8c-1.6 1.5-3 3.3-4.4 5.1-1.4 1.9-2.9 3.7-4.1 5.7a60 60 0 00-4.7 9.8c-1.3 3.4-2.6 7-3.2 10.6-1 5.8 0 11.8 1.4 17.4 1.4 5 3 9.9 5 14.6a47 47 0 007 11c4 4.6 9 8.5 14.5 11.3 3.6 1.9 7.5 3 11.4 4.3 7 2.4 14.4 2.7 21.7 3.2 4.7.3 9.4.8 14 .6 9.2-.1 18.3-1 27.4-2.2 11.7-1.7 23.4-3.4 34.8-6.6 9.6-2.5 19-5.7 28.4-8.6 8.8-2.4 17.9-3.8 27-3.5 5.3.5 10.6 1.3 16 2 3.7.5 7.5 1.2 11.3 1.6 8.8.5 17.7.4 26.5-.7 4.7-.7 9.4-1.8 14-3.1 5.5-1.9 11-3.8 16.5-5.5 8.4-2.5 16.9-5 25-8.1 7.6-3 14.8-7 22.3-10 6-2.6 11.9-5.3 18-7.2 3-1 5.8-2 8.7-2.6 7.7-1.7 15.7-1.6 23.5-1.7 4.6-.1 9.2-.5 13.6-1.8 3.2-1 6.3-2.4 9-4.2 4.3-2.9 8.4-6.1 12.8-8.7 3.6-1.8 7.4-3.4 11.3-4.5 6.1-1.2 12.5-1.1 18.6-1.6 7-.4 14.2-.7 21-2.8 6.3-1.8 12.5-4.2 18.1-7.7 4.2-2.8 7.9-6.2 11.4-9.7 1.9-2.1 3.3-4.6 4.6-7a38 38 0 004.3-18zm-5 .8c0 5.6-1.6 11-4.3 15.9-1.3 2.5-3 4.8-5.2 6.7a53.2 53.2 0 01-9.2 7.5c-5 3-10.6 5.1-16.3 6.7-5.4 1.7-11.2 2.2-16.9 2.4-6.4.4-13 .7-19.4 1.4-3.2.4-6.3 1.6-9.4 2.8-3 1.2-5.9 2.4-8.5 4.2-6 3.8-11.4 9-18.4 11-4.6 1.3-9.3 1.6-14 1.6-6.2.1-12.5.2-18.6 1-5 .7-9.8 2.4-14.6 4-11.8 4-23 9.6-34.2 14.8-10.2 4.5-21 7.4-31.7 10.7-4.6 1.4-9.3 3-13.9 4.6a123 123 0 01-10.2 2.5c-5.8 1.2-11.9 1.4-17.9 1.6-4.6 0-9.2.1-13.8-.6a442 442 0 00-25-3.3c-5-.3-10.1.3-15 .9-8.6 1-16.8 3.8-24.9 6.5a464.7 464.7 0 01-20.2 5.8c-7.2 1.8-14.6 3-22 4.2-9.8 1.6-19.7 3-29.6 3.3-6.5.4-13 .1-19.6-.4-4.6-.4-9.3-.5-13.9-1.3-3.1-.5-6.2-1.5-9.2-2.5-2.7-1-5.4-1.8-8-3-8.1-4.2-15-11-19-19.3-1.2-2.6-2-5.5-3-8.2-1.8-5.1-3.3-10.4-3.6-15.8-.4-5 1-9.8 2.8-14.3 1.3-3.7 3-7.2 5-10.5a97 97 0 015.8-7.7c1.6-2 3.6-3.4 5.8-4.7 4-2.6 8.7-3.8 13.2-5.3 8-2.3 16.2-4.8 24.6-5.3 8-.6 16-1.7 24.1-1.3 18 .3 35.8 3.4 53.7 5.5 5.2.5 10.4.5 15.6.4 5.9 0 11.8 0 17.7-.4 4.3-.4 8.7-1.2 13-1.8 4.4-.7 9-1.2 13.3-2.3 5.9-1.3 11.5-3.4 17-5.5 6-2 12-4 17.7-6.3 10.2-4.3 20.5-8.2 30.8-12 7.8-2.9 15.6-6 23.7-8 6-1.4 12.3-1.6 18.4-2.3 5.6-.7 11.2-1.9 16.9-2.4 8.4-1 17-1.8 25.5-2 6.8-.5 13.5.5 20 2 10.3 2.4 20.8 4.5 31.3 2.7 4.7-.5 9.2-2.2 13.7-3.7 5.6-2 11.3-3.8 16.9-6 11.8-4.1 31-9 42.8-4.6 1.8.6 3.6 1.3 5.2 2.2 2.4 1.5 4.7 3.2 6.7 5.2a34 34 0 018.3 22.7zm112.4 19.2c-.3-9-1.6-18.1-4-26.8-1.6-5.9-4-11.7-8-16.3-3.4-3.9-7.8-6.8-12.5-8.9-6.4-3-14-4-20.8-1.6-4.3 1.8-8.1 5.1-10 9.4-1.7 3.6-2.5 7.6-3.5 11.5-2.7 9.7-5.3 14-11.9 21.5-3.1 3.6-5 8.1-5.5 12.9-.5 5.5.8 11.2 3.8 15.9 1.6 2.7 4 4.8 6.5 6.8 6.2 5 13.8 8 21.3 10.3 6.7 1.7 13.8 2.3 20.4.4 4-1.2 7.7-3.3 11.2-5.5 2-1.4 3.8-3.2 5.5-5 2.5-2.8 4.2-6.2 5.5-9.7 1.7-4.7 2-9.9 2-15zm-4 .6c0 5.5-.6 11.2-3.1 16.2a23.1 23.1 0 01-4.6 6.4 21.4 21.4 0 01-3.9 3.3c-3.1 2-6.4 3.8-10 4.8-5.7 1.6-11.8 1-17.6-.4-7-2.1-14-4.7-19.8-9.3-2.2-1.8-4.4-3.6-5.9-6-4.6-6.9-4.7-16.9.6-23.4 2.8-3.5 5.8-6.8 8.1-10.6 2.3-3.8 3.7-8 5-12.3 1-3.7 1.7-7.6 3.2-11.2 1.4-3.6 4.6-6.5 8.2-8 5.8-1.9 12.2-1 17.6 1.5 4 1.8 7.6 4.2 10.6 7.3 4.2 4.4 6.3 10.2 7.9 15.9 2.2 8.4 3.5 17 3.7 25.8z" fill="#4ca30d" />
    <path d="M611.8 258.9c-6.5-.5-13.2-.7-19.5-2.8-3.8-1.2-7.6-2.3-11.2-4-4.7-2.5-9-5.8-12.6-9.8-2.7-3-4.9-6.4-6.6-10-1.1-2.5-1.9-5.2-2.8-7.7-1.9-5.4-3.4-11-3.6-16.7-.2-4.6 1.1-9.1 2.8-13.4 1.4-3.9 3.1-7.6 5.3-11 2.2-3 4.4-6.2 7-8.9 5.6-5 12.8-6.8 19.7-9 5.7-1.5 11.4-3.2 17.2-4.1 3.6-.6 7.3-.6 10.9-1 16.2-1.9 32.6-.4 48.7 1.7 8.3 1.2 16.6 2.1 24.8 3.1 5.7.4 11.4.4 17 .3a205.6 205.6 0 0016.2-.5c3.9-.5 7.8-1.2 11.7-1.7 5.8-.9 11.7-1.6 17.4-3.4 4.4-1.2 8.7-2.8 13-4.4 4.1-1.4 8.4-2.8 12.5-4.4 9.8-3.8 19.5-8 29.4-11.5 10.2-3.6 20.1-8 30.7-10.5 6.4-1.4 13-1.6 19.5-2.4 8.8-1.4 17.7-2.5 26.5-3.4 5-.6 10.1-.6 15.2-.8 9.8-.8 19.3 2.3 28.8 4 4.8 1 9.6 1.5 14.5 1.4 5.8-.2 11.6-1.2 17-3.2 4.8-1.6 9.5-3.1 14.2-4.8 3.6-1.3 7.2-2.8 11-4 8.6-2.5 17.5-4.5 26.5-4.7 3.5 0 7.1.2 10.5 1.2 2.1.7 4.2 1.5 6.2 2.6a39 39 0 015.6 4c4 3.7 6.7 8.8 8.4 14 3 10.5.9 21.3-5.7 30a61.3 61.3 0 01-10.6 9.4 60 60 0 01-9.6 4.9c-4.6 1.6-9.3 3.3-14.1 4-7.8 1.2-15.8 1-23.7 1.8-3.3.2-6.8.3-10 1.3-2.5.7-4.8 1.6-7.2 2.6-2 .8-3.9 1.6-5.6 2.8-5 3-9.4 6.8-14.4 9.7-5.4 3-11.6 3.6-17.6 3.7-6.6.1-13.2 0-19.8 1-2.5.3-5.1.8-7.7 1.5-2.5.8-5 1.7-7.5 2.5-11 3.8-21.5 8.8-32 13.8-10.9 5-22.5 8.2-33.9 11.7-4.6 1.4-9.3 3-13.9 4.6-3.6 1-7.3 2-11 2.7-9.2 1.6-18.8 1.6-28.2 1.1-7.7-1-15.4-2.2-23.2-3.1a49 49 0 00-12-.4c-8.5.5-17 2.2-25 5-10.6 3.3-21.1 6.6-31.9 9-8 2-16.1 3.1-24.3 4.4-9.6 1.3-19.3 2.3-29 2.4-4.6.2-9.3-.4-14-.6zM1091 152.3c2.6-3 5-6 6.8-9.3a65 65 0 005-13.5c1.1-4.2 1.9-8.6 4.4-12.1 2.4-3 5.8-5.3 9.7-5.7 5-.9 10.3.2 15 2.5 3.8 1.8 7.5 4.2 10.3 7.4 5 5.6 7.1 13 8.8 20.3 1.3 6.5 2.3 13.1 2.5 19.8.1 5.9-.4 12-3.1 17.4-.8 1.5-1.7 3-2.7 4.3a38.9 38.9 0 01-3.7 3.9c-1.5 1.3-3.2 2.2-5 3.2-3 1.7-6.1 3.2-9.6 3.7-7 1-14.2-.3-20.7-2.8-4.7-1.8-9.4-3.8-13.4-6.9-3.3-2.5-6.5-5.4-8.2-9.2-2.1-4.8-2.5-10.3-1-15.3 1-2.9 3-5.4 5-7.7z" fill="#71ce01" />
    <path d="M1096 156.5c2.7-3.2 5.3-6.6 7.5-10.3a71 71 0 005.4-14.2c1-3.5 1.4-7.4 3.3-10.5 1-1.3 2.2-2.2 3.6-2.9.8-.3 1.7-.4 2.5-.5 3.7-.5 7.4.4 10.6 2a25 25 0 018.2 5.7c3.8 4 5.3 9.5 6.7 14.8 2.2 9.3 4.4 22.7 2 32a19.8 19.8 0 01-7 10.3c-2.8 1.8-5.7 3.6-9 4.4-5.7 1.4-11.8.4-17.4-1.5-3.1-1.2-6.3-2.4-9.3-4a35 35 0 01-6.8-4.9 12.7 12.7 0 01-3.2-4 15 15 0 01-.8-10.8c.7-2.1 2.2-3.9 3.6-5.6zM586 174c7.9-2.5 15.9-5 24.1-6.2 6.8-.5 13.7-1.2 20.5-1.5 3.3-.2 6.6 0 9.9.1 12.5.5 24.9 2.4 37.2 4 5.3.4 10.4 1.4 15.7 1.7 4.5.3 9 .3 13.5.2 6.3 0 12.5-.1 18.8-.6 4.7-.5 9.4-1.4 14-2 4.6-.7 9.1-1.3 13.5-2.5 5.3-1.3 10.5-3.2 15.6-5 3.7-1.4 7.5-2.6 11.2-4 4.8-1.7 9.5-3.7 14.3-5.7A967 967 0 01811 146c10.3-3.6 20.3-8.2 31-10.6 5.3-1 10.8-1.3 16.2-2 4.2-.3 8.3-1.2 12.4-1.7 9.1-1 18.3-2.3 27.5-2.4 3.7-.2 7.4-.4 11.1 0 8.5 1 16.8 3.8 25.3 4.7 3.3.4 6.6.7 9.9.6 4.2-.2 8.3-.7 12.4-1.6 7-1.9 14-4.5 20.8-6.8 6.4-2.4 12.8-4.8 19.5-6.2 5.5-1.1 11-2.1 16.6-2.2 3.4 0 6.9.4 10 1.8 2 .7 4 1.9 5.7 3.2.8.7 1.6 1.3 2.3 2 .7.7 1.2 1.5 1.8 2.3a27 27 0 013 25.1 33 33 0 01-3.6 6.7c-1 1.1-2 2.1-3.1 3.1-2.2 2.1-4.5 4-7 5.6a53.6 53.6 0 01-10 4.5c-5.5 2-11.2 3.3-17.2 3.5a584.3 584.3 0 00-17.4 1.1c-2.8.3-5.7.4-8.5 1-3 .8-6 2-9 3.1-2 .9-4 1.6-5.8 2.7-5.4 3-10 7.2-15.4 10.3-1.2.7-2.5 1.2-3.8 1.6-1.6.4-3.2.7-4.8 1-9.9.8-19.9 0-29.7 1.9-3.4.6-6.7 1.6-10 2.7a138 138 0 00-14.2 5.3c-3.5 1.6-7.1 3-10.6 4.6-5.5 2.5-10.9 5.3-16.4 7.5-8.4 3.4-17 5.9-25.7 8.5-5.3 1.6-10.7 3.4-16 5.3-5.5 1.5-11.2 2.9-17 3.3-6.6.4-13.3.6-20 .2-8.5-1.3-17-2.5-25.7-3.5-4.9-.5-9.8 0-14.7.4-9.7.9-19 3.6-28.2 6.7-8.3 2.6-16.6 5.1-25.1 7-9.3 2.1-18.7 3.6-28.1 4.9-9.4 1-18.8 2-28.3 1.7-4.7-.3-9.5-.5-14.2-1-2.7-.2-5.4-.3-8-.8-2.7-.5-5.3-1.4-8-2.2-2.3-.8-4.7-1.6-7-2.7-5.5-2.8-10.4-7-13.8-12.3a36 36 0 01-4.1-8.9c-1-3-2-6-2.9-8.9-1-4-1.7-8-1-12.2.8-4.1 2.4-8.1 4.1-12 1-1.8 1.8-3.7 3-5.3 1.9-2.5 3.7-5 5.8-7.2 3.1-2.6 6.9-4.3 10.7-5.5z" fill="url(#b)" />
    <path d="M264.8 231.8l30.2-3.1 3.2 35-30.5 2.4zm-88.9 9l60-6.6 4.6 41-60.3 6.1zM25 268.4l74.1-9.2 3.4 29-74.1 8.8z" fill="#71ce01" />
    <path d="M1141.6 123.6c6.6 7.9 9 23.9 9.9 34 .8 9.5 0 20-7.2 27-1.8 1.8-4 3.2-6.1 4.4-3.1 1.7-6.4 3.2-10 3.6-7.5 1-15-1-21.9-4-5.3-2-10.3-5-14.3-9.1-2.6-2.5-4.1-5.9-4.9-9.3-1-6.1.4-11.6 4.6-16.1 3-3.5 5.8-7 8-11.1 2-4 3.5-8.4 4.6-12.7 1-3.6 1.6-7.3 3.3-10.6 1.3-2.4 3.6-4.2 6-5.4 3.1-1.3 6.6-1.4 9.8-1 6.5 1 14 5.1 18.2 10.3z" fill="#92f100" />
    <path d="M1096.2 133.5c-2.2 6-6 11.5-12.2 13.8-4 1.2-8.8.6-12.5-1.7-3-1.9-5.1-4.4-5.8-8-.7-3.1-.7-6.5-1.4-9.7-.6-2.5-1.6-4.9-2.5-7.2-1-2.3-1.4-4.7-1.4-7.2-.1-3.6.9-7.6 3.4-10.3 3.3-3.2 8.4-2.4 12.5-1.7 7.7 1.6 13.6 2.9 18.3 9.7 4.5 6.5 4.4 15.2 1.6 22.3zm-30.3 62.2c-2.6 6.6-7.6 11.5-15.1 9.8-4-.8-7.7-3.3-10-6.7-2-4-2-9.3-.8-13.6.3-1.7 1.4-3.1 2.6-4.5 1-1.3 2.2-2.8 3.4-4 4.8-4.6 12-8.7 18.8-8.4 5.2.6 11.5 2.7 13 8.2.7 2.5.3 5.3-1 7.5-.6 1.4-1.4 2.8-2.9 3.4-6 2.5-5.6 2.3-8 8.3zm-79.8 23a57 57 0 00-2.7 8.7c-.6 2.4-1 5.2-3 6.9-2.3 2-5.6 2.6-8.6 2.9-2.9.3-5.9.2-8.5-1.1-1.9-1-3.6-2.3-5-3.8-3.2-3.4-.4-8.2.7-12 .7-1.7.8-2.6-.4-4.1-2.4-3.8-6.6-8.5-4-13.1.7-1.4 1.7-2.7 3.2-3.4 2.8-1.2 5.9-1.6 8.7-2.9 1.6-.6 2.9-1.9 4.4-2.7a11 11 0 0110.5.8c2 1.4 4.4 2.6 5.7 4.7 2.1 4.3 2 9.4 1 14-.4 1.8-1.3 3.4-2 5zm-82.4 38.5c-1.5.6-2.5 2-3.5 3.2a21 21 0 01-3.8 3.7c-3.9 3.1-11.4 4.2-15.9 2-1.7-1-3.1-2.4-4.6-3.7-2.2-1.9-4.5-3.9-6.3-6.2-1.2-1.5-2.7-3-3.6-4.7-2.6-4.9-2.5-9.5-2-14.8.4-4.8 4.2-9.1 9-9.6 1.6-.2 3.2-.5 4.7-.7 1.4-.1 2.8-.2 4.1-.7 3.9-1.8 7.7-4 12-4.4 2.4-.3 4.8 1 6.2 2.8.7 1.2 1 2.4 1.8 3.5.5.8 1 1.7 1.7 2.3 1.4 1 3 1.8 4.4 2.6 4.1 2.3 10.9 4 11.6 9.5.4 4.2-3.1 7.6-6 10.1-2.9 2.5-6.5 3.5-9.8 5z" fill="#ffff9f" />
    <path d="M115 302.4c0-3.3 3.7-5.5 6.6-4 3.3 1.5 3.3 6.4 0 8-3 1.5-6.6-.8-6.5-4zM55 245c0 3.4.1 6.9-.7 10.2-.6 2-1 4.2-2 6l-.2.2-.2.2c-2.7 1-5.9 1-8.8 1.4-4.8.5-9.7 1-14.5 1.7-2.7.5-5.7.8-7.9 2.7-.8.6-1.2 1.5-1.8 2.3l-.1 0-.1 0-.1 0-.2 0c-1-1.2-1.4-2.7-2.1-4-.8-1.6-1.8-3.1-2.6-4.7-1-2.5-1-5.3-1.7-7.9 14.4-1.9 28.7-5.3 43-8zm49.4-11.6c.1 3.5.4 6.9.7 10.3-9.4.4-15 .8-23.4-4.5-.3-3.5-1.2-7-1.6-10.5-.2-2-.8-4.6 1-6.1 4.1-3.4 10.4-1.8 14.6.4 4.6 2 7 6 8.7 10.4zM79 322.8c-3 .6-6 1-9 1.5-1.2.1-2.3.5-3.5.5l-.1-.1c-.4-1-.2-2-.1-3 .2-1.9 1.7-3.4 3.2-4.3 3.4-1.7 7.7-2.3 11.3-1.2 1.5.5 3.2 1.1 4 2.5.3 1 0 2-.2 3-1.8.5-3.8.7-5.6 1zm130.6-13.2c-5.7-1-11.4-1.7-17-3-9.8-2.4-19.4-5.7-28-11 1.6-1 3.2-1.8 5-1.9 3.8-.1 7.5.6 11.2 1 10.8 1.3 21.7 2 32.6 3 15.5 1.3 31.2.7 46.7-1 8.6-1.1 13.1-.1 16.2 8.7a52 52 0 012.3 10c.5 3 .2 6-1.2 8.7-4.2-1-8.4-2.2-12.3-4.1-3-1.5-5.6-3.5-8.6-4.9a27.8 27.8 0 00-10.3-2.6c-5.8-.4-11.7-.2-17.5-.6-6.4-.3-12.8-1.2-19.1-2.3z" fill="#b58254" />
    <path d="M1205 223.9c-13.5-.9-32.7-3.6-46-1.3-18 3.7-37.4 9-54.2 16.5-4.6 2.4-11.4 7.4-15.6 10.6-9.1 6.3-20.6 13-30.5 17.9-15.9 8-35.8 17.6-51.8 25.2-5.7 2.4-12.4 4.3-18.6 4.6-13.7 1-31-1.2-44.8.5-14.2 2.3-29 7.1-42.4 12.3-6.6 2.5-24 11.5-30.8 13.7-5.7 1.3-12.6 1.8-18.4.4-11-4.9-24.9-12-36.4-15.5-18.7-5.3-39.6-8.6-59-6-17.6 2.5-37 11.8-53.6 18-11.3 4.6-25.2 11.9-37.6 12.3-20.2 1.9-43.5-2.2-63.7-3.4-8 0-31.6 2.2-40 2.9-13 1.2-26.1-3.2-37.8-8.5-6.2-2.6-13-7.9-19.8-9-45.4 4.9-93.3-8.4-138.7-2.7l-3.5 1.3c-4.8 2.2-9.5 7-13.2 10.7-3.6 3.3-9.5 7.2-13.7 9.9-17.7-3.5-50.6-7.1-67.2-13.2-17.7-9.8-16.7-8.6-36.9-9-27.9-2.6-60.2-6.2-80-28.2-18.4-19.9-27.4-54-21.2-80.4-15.2-2-123.3 18.7-140.7 21.4l23.4 125.6c51.4-9.2 112.6-22 164.9-20.5 20.8 5.6 47 6.4 68.4 9 35.4 7.2 80.9 16.5 116 25.5l.7-24.7-2.4-3.3-1-2.2-.2-1.3c0-.9.1-2.5.3-3.3l.4-1.4 1-1.6 1.4-1.3c5.2-3.6 11.9-5.3 18.2-5.6 39.7-1.5 82 7 121.8 3.5l2 .4c34.4 17.4 42.2 19 80.6 15.1 23.9-2 49.4 3.5 73.4 2.5 10.2-.2 21.6-2.2 31-6.2 38.5-15.2 68.3-32.2 111.2-22.4 20.2 3.3 38.2 19.2 58.8 20.3 17.8 1.2 34.5-12 50.8-17.3 12.2-4.3 27.2-9.4 40.2-10.2 12.1-.3 28.6 1.4 40.6-.5 23.7-3.3 54.6-22.7 76.2-32.4 15-7.2 34.4-22.4 49.6-29.2 16.2-6.3 34.2-11.5 51.6-13.6 16.8 0 37.3 2.5 54.1 2.6l6.4-7.6-23.3-1zM84.6 321.8c-3.5.7-13.9 2.4-17.6 3l-.5-.2-.2-.9 0-1.7.4-1.5.7-1.2 1.3-1.3 1.3-.8 1.7-.7c1-.4 3.5-.7 4.6-.8l2.7 0 2.6.7 2.3 1.2.6.5.4.6 0 1.1-.3 2zm48.6-14.5l-1 2.2-1.4 1.8-1.7 1.4-2 1c-1.5.6-26.6 4.4-29 4.8l-.9-.1-.8-.6c-1.3-1.4-6-6.8-7.5-7.8l-2-1.3-2.2-1-2.3-.5-5.8-.6-1.2-8-3.8.4 1.1 8-3.2.7-3.2 1.5-2.7 1.8-2.8 2.7-1.6 2.3-1.3 2.5-1.4 4-.7 4.3-.4.4-.4.2c-5.9 1.2-13.4 2.6-19.4 2.4l-3.3-.7-3-1.1-2.6-1.5-2.4-2-1.5-1.7-1.4-2c-1.4-2.9-2.4-7.2-3-10.2-2.1-14.2-11-55.7-13.8-70.2l0-1 1.2-.3 2.2-.3 2.2 13.6.4.6.5.2c16.8-2 53-9.9 70-13.3l.4-.4.1-.9c-.4-2.9-2-11-1.7-13.9l.3-1 .8-1 1.3-1 1.4-.5 1.7-.4c5.1-.4 10.5 1.8 14.4 5.2.6.6 1.7 2 2.1 2.7l2.3 4.8c.5 11.6 2.5 24.7 7.4 35.2 4.2 11.6 11.8 21.8 20.5 30.3l.7 2 .6 2.9 0 2-.2 1.4z" fill="#b4b4b4" stroke-opacity=".5" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".3" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Now I would like to filter out one part of the SVG where `fill` is equal to

```
"#92f100"
```

Is it it possible to create a new SVG that only shows the above part?

Comment: @enxaneta thanks for the edit! Is there a tool that does the outlining automatically?

Comment: you can copy paste the code in codepen and format the code - if this was the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a simple js query like so:

```
let filtered = document.querySelectorAll('[fill="#92f100"]');
```

and then remove these elements

```
  filtered.forEach(function(el,i){
    el.remove()
  })
```

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let filterColor = '#92f100';
let filtered = svg.querySelectorAll('[fill="' + filterColor + '"]');

//filterOut(filtered);

function filterOut(filtered) {
  filtered.forEach(function(el, i) {
    el.remove()
  })
}

//getFiltered(svg, filtered);
function getFiltered(svg, filtered) {
  let defs = svg.querySelector('defs');
  svg.innerHTML = '';
  svg.appendChild(defs);
  filtered.forEach(function(el, i) {
    svg.appendChild(el);
  })
}
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 75%
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="filterOut(filtered)" type="button">filter out (remove selection)</button>
  <button onclick="getFiltered(svg, filtered)" type="button">get filtered (reduce to selection)</button></p>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1223" height="331" viewBox="-2 47 1223 331">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="a">
      <path d="M84.5 208.2c77.3-15 161.7-47.3 237.1-70.1C529.6 81.8 747.8 29.3 962.2 6.4c34-3 72.4-4.4 104.2 9.8 26 11.3 55.5 31.9 80.4 45.2 15.2 8.3 36.4 17.8 47.7 31.6 22 24.8 33.4 63.8 19.7 95.2-44.8 77.5-174.6 122.4-256.8 149.3-86.8 19-180.7 22.3-269.3 22-157.6-3-324.7-17.4-481.4-33.2-28.6-2.3-63-2.1-91.7-.1-19.7.9-54.5 6.2-74.3 3.3l-4.2-1.1c-3.3-1.5-9.7-5.8-12.7-8l-5.5-5.5C1.9 293.5 2 263.4 8.3 238.3l2.5-5 3.6-4.1 4.7-3c20-8.7 44.1-13.8 65.4-18z" />
    </clipPath>
    <pattern id="b" width="39.37" height="39.37" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <path fill="#71CE01" d="M0 0h100v100H0z" />
      <path fill="#359200" opacity=".15" d="M0 0h50v100H0z" />
      <path fill="#359200" opacity=".15" d="M0 0h100v50H0z" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="rotate(366.63 612 182)">
    <path d="M-62-492l1348 0 0 1348-1348 0z" fill="#358806" />
    <path d="M1050 142.3a39 39 0 00-9.7-25.3c-1.5-1.6-3.3-3-5.2-4.4-1.9-1.4-4-2.5-6.1-3.4-7.2-3.3-15.3-3.4-23-2.4-7.4.9-14.6 2.5-21.7 4.7-7 2.4-13.8 5.1-20.8 7.4-4 1.3-7.9 2.8-12 3.4-8.7 1.6-17.6.3-26.2-1.6-5.4-1.2-11-2.6-16.6-3-4.7-.5-9.4 0-14.1.1-7.2.2-14.3 1.2-21.5 2-4.9.4-9.8 1.4-14.7 2-5.6.7-11.3 1-17 2-12.4 2.4-24 7.8-36 12-5.2 2-10.4 3.9-15.5 6-5.6 2.3-11.1 4.6-16.8 6.5-7.8 2.5-15.3 5.8-23.2 7.7-5.3 1.4-10.8 2-16.2 2.8-3 .4-6 1-9 1.3-4 .3-8 .4-11.8.5-9 0-18 .4-26.8-1-8.8-1-17.6-2.3-26.4-3.3-3.8-.4-7.7-.8-11.5-1.1-4.7-.3-9.4-.5-14-.6-6.6 0-13 .6-19.6 1.2-6.8.3-13.6 1.7-20.2 3.5-3.5 1-7 2-10.5 3.1-4 1.2-7.8 2.6-11.3 4.7a34 34 0 00-5.3 3.8c-1.6 1.5-3 3.3-4.4 5.1-1.4 1.9-2.9 3.7-4.1 5.7a60 60 0 00-4.7 9.8c-1.3 3.4-2.6 7-3.2 10.6-1 5.8 0 11.8 1.4 17.4 1.4 5 3 9.9 5 14.6a47 47 0 007 11c4 4.6 9 8.5 14.5 11.3 3.6 1.9 7.5 3 11.4 4.3 7 2.4 14.4 2.7 21.7 3.2 4.7.3 9.4.8 14 .6 9.2-.1 18.3-1 27.4-2.2 11.7-1.7 23.4-3.4 34.8-6.6 9.6-2.5 19-5.7 28.4-8.6 8.8-2.4 17.9-3.8 27-3.5 5.3.5 10.6 1.3 16 2 3.7.5 7.5 1.2 11.3 1.6 8.8.5 17.7.4 26.5-.7 4.7-.7 9.4-1.8 14-3.1 5.5-1.9 11-3.8 16.5-5.5 8.4-2.5 16.9-5 25-8.1 7.6-3 14.8-7 22.3-10 6-2.6 11.9-5.3 18-7.2 3-1 5.8-2 8.7-2.6 7.7-1.7 15.7-1.6 23.5-1.7 4.6-.1 9.2-.5 13.6-1.8 3.2-1 6.3-2.4 9-4.2 4.3-2.9 8.4-6.1 12.8-8.7 3.6-1.8 7.4-3.4 11.3-4.5 6.1-1.2 12.5-1.1 18.6-1.6 7-.4 14.2-.7 21-2.8 6.3-1.8 12.5-4.2 18.1-7.7 4.2-2.8 7.9-6.2 11.4-9.7 1.9-2.1 3.3-4.6 4.6-7a38 38 0 004.3-18zm-5 .8c0 5.6-1.6 11-4.3 15.9-1.3 2.5-3 4.8-5.2 6.7a53.2 53.2 0 01-9.2 7.5c-5 3-10.6 5.1-16.3 6.7-5.4 1.7-11.2 2.2-16.9 2.4-6.4.4-13 .7-19.4 1.4-3.2.4-6.3 1.6-9.4 2.8-3 1.2-5.9 2.4-8.5 4.2-6 3.8-11.4 9-18.4 11-4.6 1.3-9.3 1.6-14 1.6-6.2.1-12.5.2-18.6 1-5 .7-9.8 2.4-14.6 4-11.8 4-23 9.6-34.2 14.8-10.2 4.5-21 7.4-31.7 10.7-4.6 1.4-9.3 3-13.9 4.6a123 123 0 01-10.2 2.5c-5.8 1.2-11.9 1.4-17.9 1.6-4.6 0-9.2.1-13.8-.6a442 442 0 00-25-3.3c-5-.3-10.1.3-15 .9-8.6 1-16.8 3.8-24.9 6.5a464.7 464.7 0 01-20.2 5.8c-7.2 1.8-14.6 3-22 4.2-9.8 1.6-19.7 3-29.6 3.3-6.5.4-13 .1-19.6-.4-4.6-.4-9.3-.5-13.9-1.3-3.1-.5-6.2-1.5-9.2-2.5-2.7-1-5.4-1.8-8-3-8.1-4.2-15-11-19-19.3-1.2-2.6-2-5.5-3-8.2-1.8-5.1-3.3-10.4-3.6-15.8-.4-5 1-9.8 2.8-14.3 1.3-3.7 3-7.2 5-10.5a97 97 0 015.8-7.7c1.6-2 3.6-3.4 5.8-4.7 4-2.6 8.7-3.8 13.2-5.3 8-2.3 16.2-4.8 24.6-5.3 8-.6 16-1.7 24.1-1.3 18 .3 35.8 3.4 53.7 5.5 5.2.5 10.4.5 15.6.4 5.9 0 11.8 0 17.7-.4 4.3-.4 8.7-1.2 13-1.8 4.4-.7 9-1.2 13.3-2.3 5.9-1.3 11.5-3.4 17-5.5 6-2 12-4 17.7-6.3 10.2-4.3 20.5-8.2 30.8-12 7.8-2.9 15.6-6 23.7-8 6-1.4 12.3-1.6 18.4-2.3 5.6-.7 11.2-1.9 16.9-2.4 8.4-1 17-1.8 25.5-2 6.8-.5 13.5.5 20 2 10.3 2.4 20.8 4.5 31.3 2.7 4.7-.5 9.2-2.2 13.7-3.7 5.6-2 11.3-3.8 16.9-6 11.8-4.1 31-9 42.8-4.6 1.8.6 3.6 1.3 5.2 2.2 2.4 1.5 4.7 3.2 6.7 5.2a34 34 0 018.3 22.7zm112.4 19.2c-.3-9-1.6-18.1-4-26.8-1.6-5.9-4-11.7-8-16.3-3.4-3.9-7.8-6.8-12.5-8.9-6.4-3-14-4-20.8-1.6-4.3 1.8-8.1 5.1-10 9.4-1.7 3.6-2.5 7.6-3.5 11.5-2.7 9.7-5.3 14-11.9 21.5-3.1 3.6-5 8.1-5.5 12.9-.5 5.5.8 11.2 3.8 15.9 1.6 2.7 4 4.8 6.5 6.8 6.2 5 13.8 8 21.3 10.3 6.7 1.7 13.8 2.3 20.4.4 4-1.2 7.7-3.3 11.2-5.5 2-1.4 3.8-3.2 5.5-5 2.5-2.8 4.2-6.2 5.5-9.7 1.7-4.7 2-9.9 2-15zm-4 .6c0 5.5-.6 11.2-3.1 16.2a23.1 23.1 0 01-4.6 6.4 21.4 21.4 0 01-3.9 3.3c-3.1 2-6.4 3.8-10 4.8-5.7 1.6-11.8 1-17.6-.4-7-2.1-14-4.7-19.8-9.3-2.2-1.8-4.4-3.6-5.9-6-4.6-6.9-4.7-16.9.6-23.4 2.8-3.5 5.8-6.8 8.1-10.6 2.3-3.8 3.7-8 5-12.3 1-3.7 1.7-7.6 3.2-11.2 1.4-3.6 4.6-6.5 8.2-8 5.8-1.9 12.2-1 17.6 1.5 4 1.8 7.6 4.2 10.6 7.3 4.2 4.4 6.3 10.2 7.9 15.9 2.2 8.4 3.5 17 3.7 25.8z" fill="#4ca30d" />
    <path d="M611.8 258.9c-6.5-.5-13.2-.7-19.5-2.8-3.8-1.2-7.6-2.3-11.2-4-4.7-2.5-9-5.8-12.6-9.8-2.7-3-4.9-6.4-6.6-10-1.1-2.5-1.9-5.2-2.8-7.7-1.9-5.4-3.4-11-3.6-16.7-.2-4.6 1.1-9.1 2.8-13.4 1.4-3.9 3.1-7.6 5.3-11 2.2-3 4.4-6.2 7-8.9 5.6-5 12.8-6.8 19.7-9 5.7-1.5 11.4-3.2 17.2-4.1 3.6-.6 7.3-.6 10.9-1 16.2-1.9 32.6-.4 48.7 1.7 8.3 1.2 16.6 2.1 24.8 3.1 5.7.4 11.4.4 17 .3a205.6 205.6 0 0016.2-.5c3.9-.5 7.8-1.2 11.7-1.7 5.8-.9 11.7-1.6 17.4-3.4 4.4-1.2 8.7-2.8 13-4.4 4.1-1.4 8.4-2.8 12.5-4.4 9.8-3.8 19.5-8 29.4-11.5 10.2-3.6 20.1-8 30.7-10.5 6.4-1.4 13-1.6 19.5-2.4 8.8-1.4 17.7-2.5 26.5-3.4 5-.6 10.1-.6 15.2-.8 9.8-.8 19.3 2.3 28.8 4 4.8 1 9.6 1.5 14.5 1.4 5.8-.2 11.6-1.2 17-3.2 4.8-1.6 9.5-3.1 14.2-4.8 3.6-1.3 7.2-2.8 11-4 8.6-2.5 17.5-4.5 26.5-4.7 3.5 0 7.1.2 10.5 1.2 2.1.7 4.2 1.5 6.2 2.6a39 39 0 015.6 4c4 3.7 6.7 8.8 8.4 14 3 10.5.9 21.3-5.7 30a61.3 61.3 0 01-10.6 9.4 60 60 0 01-9.6 4.9c-4.6 1.6-9.3 3.3-14.1 4-7.8 1.2-15.8 1-23.7 1.8-3.3.2-6.8.3-10 1.3-2.5.7-4.8 1.6-7.2 2.6-2 .8-3.9 1.6-5.6 2.8-5 3-9.4 6.8-14.4 9.7-5.4 3-11.6 3.6-17.6 3.7-6.6.1-13.2 0-19.8 1-2.5.3-5.1.8-7.7 1.5-2.5.8-5 1.7-7.5 2.5-11 3.8-21.5 8.8-32 13.8-10.9 5-22.5 8.2-33.9 11.7-4.6 1.4-9.3 3-13.9 4.6-3.6 1-7.3 2-11 2.7-9.2 1.6-18.8 1.6-28.2 1.1-7.7-1-15.4-2.2-23.2-3.1a49 49 0 00-12-.4c-8.5.5-17 2.2-25 5-10.6 3.3-21.1 6.6-31.9 9-8 2-16.1 3.1-24.3 4.4-9.6 1.3-19.3 2.3-29 2.4-4.6.2-9.3-.4-14-.6zM1091 152.3c2.6-3 5-6 6.8-9.3a65 65 0 005-13.5c1.1-4.2 1.9-8.6 4.4-12.1 2.4-3 5.8-5.3 9.7-5.7 5-.9 10.3.2 15 2.5 3.8 1.8 7.5 4.2 10.3 7.4 5 5.6 7.1 13 8.8 20.3 1.3 6.5 2.3 13.1 2.5 19.8.1 5.9-.4 12-3.1 17.4-.8 1.5-1.7 3-2.7 4.3a38.9 38.9 0 01-3.7 3.9c-1.5 1.3-3.2 2.2-5 3.2-3 1.7-6.1 3.2-9.6 3.7-7 1-14.2-.3-20.7-2.8-4.7-1.8-9.4-3.8-13.4-6.9-3.3-2.5-6.5-5.4-8.2-9.2-2.1-4.8-2.5-10.3-1-15.3 1-2.9 3-5.4 5-7.7z" fill="#71ce01" />
    <path d="M1096 156.5c2.7-3.2 5.3-6.6 7.5-10.3a71 71 0 005.4-14.2c1-3.5 1.4-7.4 3.3-10.5 1-1.3 2.2-2.2 3.6-2.9.8-.3 1.7-.4 2.5-.5 3.7-.5 7.4.4 10.6 2a25 25 0 018.2 5.7c3.8 4 5.3 9.5 6.7 14.8 2.2 9.3 4.4 22.7 2 32a19.8 19.8 0 01-7 10.3c-2.8 1.8-5.7 3.6-9 4.4-5.7 1.4-11.8.4-17.4-1.5-3.1-1.2-6.3-2.4-9.3-4a35 35 0 01-6.8-4.9 12.7 12.7 0 01-3.2-4 15 15 0 01-.8-10.8c.7-2.1 2.2-3.9 3.6-5.6zM586 174c7.9-2.5 15.9-5 24.1-6.2 6.8-.5 13.7-1.2 20.5-1.5 3.3-.2 6.6 0 9.9.1 12.5.5 24.9 2.4 37.2 4 5.3.4 10.4 1.4 15.7 1.7 4.5.3 9 .3 13.5.2 6.3 0 12.5-.1 18.8-.6 4.7-.5 9.4-1.4 14-2 4.6-.7 9.1-1.3 13.5-2.5 5.3-1.3 10.5-3.2 15.6-5 3.7-1.4 7.5-2.6 11.2-4 4.8-1.7 9.5-3.7 14.3-5.7A967 967 0 01811 146c10.3-3.6 20.3-8.2 31-10.6 5.3-1 10.8-1.3 16.2-2 4.2-.3 8.3-1.2 12.4-1.7 9.1-1 18.3-2.3 27.5-2.4 3.7-.2 7.4-.4 11.1 0 8.5 1 16.8 3.8 25.3 4.7 3.3.4 6.6.7 9.9.6 4.2-.2 8.3-.7 12.4-1.6 7-1.9 14-4.5 20.8-6.8 6.4-2.4 12.8-4.8 19.5-6.2 5.5-1.1 11-2.1 16.6-2.2 3.4 0 6.9.4 10 1.8 2 .7 4 1.9 5.7 3.2.8.7 1.6 1.3 2.3 2 .7.7 1.2 1.5 1.8 2.3a27 27 0 013 25.1 33 33 0 01-3.6 6.7c-1 1.1-2 2.1-3.1 3.1-2.2 2.1-4.5 4-7 5.6a53.6 53.6 0 01-10 4.5c-5.5 2-11.2 3.3-17.2 3.5a584.3 584.3 0 00-17.4 1.1c-2.8.3-5.7.4-8.5 1-3 .8-6 2-9 3.1-2 .9-4 1.6-5.8 2.7-5.4 3-10 7.2-15.4 10.3-1.2.7-2.5 1.2-3.8 1.6-1.6.4-3.2.7-4.8 1-9.9.8-19.9 0-29.7 1.9-3.4.6-6.7 1.6-10 2.7a138 138 0 00-14.2 5.3c-3.5 1.6-7.1 3-10.6 4.6-5.5 2.5-10.9 5.3-16.4 7.5-8.4 3.4-17 5.9-25.7 8.5-5.3 1.6-10.7 3.4-16 5.3-5.5 1.5-11.2 2.9-17 3.3-6.6.4-13.3.6-20 .2-8.5-1.3-17-2.5-25.7-3.5-4.9-.5-9.8 0-14.7.4-9.7.9-19 3.6-28.2 6.7-8.3 2.6-16.6 5.1-25.1 7-9.3 2.1-18.7 3.6-28.1 4.9-9.4 1-18.8 2-28.3 1.7-4.7-.3-9.5-.5-14.2-1-2.7-.2-5.4-.3-8-.8-2.7-.5-5.3-1.4-8-2.2-2.3-.8-4.7-1.6-7-2.7-5.5-2.8-10.4-7-13.8-12.3a36 36 0 01-4.1-8.9c-1-3-2-6-2.9-8.9-1-4-1.7-8-1-12.2.8-4.1 2.4-8.1 4.1-12 1-1.8 1.8-3.7 3-5.3 1.9-2.5 3.7-5 5.8-7.2 3.1-2.6 6.9-4.3 10.7-5.5z" fill="url(#b)" />
    <path d="M264.8 231.8l30.2-3.1 3.2 35-30.5 2.4zm-88.9 9l60-6.6 4.6 41-60.3 6.1zM25 268.4l74.1-9.2 3.4 29-74.1 8.8z" fill="#71ce01" />
    <path d="M1141.6 123.6c6.6 7.9 9 23.9 9.9 34 .8 9.5 0 20-7.2 27-1.8 1.8-4 3.2-6.1 4.4-3.1 1.7-6.4 3.2-10 3.6-7.5 1-15-1-21.9-4-5.3-2-10.3-5-14.3-9.1-2.6-2.5-4.1-5.9-4.9-9.3-1-6.1.4-11.6 4.6-16.1 3-3.5 5.8-7 8-11.1 2-4 3.5-8.4 4.6-12.7 1-3.6 1.6-7.3 3.3-10.6 1.3-2.4 3.6-4.2 6-5.4 3.1-1.3 6.6-1.4 9.8-1 6.5 1 14 5.1 18.2 10.3z" fill="#92f100" />
    <path d="M1096.2 133.5c-2.2 6-6 11.5-12.2 13.8-4 1.2-8.8.6-12.5-1.7-3-1.9-5.1-4.4-5.8-8-.7-3.1-.7-6.5-1.4-9.7-.6-2.5-1.6-4.9-2.5-7.2-1-2.3-1.4-4.7-1.4-7.2-.1-3.6.9-7.6 3.4-10.3 3.3-3.2 8.4-2.4 12.5-1.7 7.7 1.6 13.6 2.9 18.3 9.7 4.5 6.5 4.4 15.2 1.6 22.3zm-30.3 62.2c-2.6 6.6-7.6 11.5-15.1 9.8-4-.8-7.7-3.3-10-6.7-2-4-2-9.3-.8-13.6.3-1.7 1.4-3.1 2.6-4.5 1-1.3 2.2-2.8 3.4-4 4.8-4.6 12-8.7 18.8-8.4 5.2.6 11.5 2.7 13 8.2.7 2.5.3 5.3-1 7.5-.6 1.4-1.4 2.8-2.9 3.4-6 2.5-5.6 2.3-8 8.3zm-79.8 23a57 57 0 00-2.7 8.7c-.6 2.4-1 5.2-3 6.9-2.3 2-5.6 2.6-8.6 2.9-2.9.3-5.9.2-8.5-1.1-1.9-1-3.6-2.3-5-3.8-3.2-3.4-.4-8.2.7-12 .7-1.7.8-2.6-.4-4.1-2.4-3.8-6.6-8.5-4-13.1.7-1.4 1.7-2.7 3.2-3.4 2.8-1.2 5.9-1.6 8.7-2.9 1.6-.6 2.9-1.9 4.4-2.7a11 11 0 0110.5.8c2 1.4 4.4 2.6 5.7 4.7 2.1 4.3 2 9.4 1 14-.4 1.8-1.3 3.4-2 5zm-82.4 38.5c-1.5.6-2.5 2-3.5 3.2a21 21 0 01-3.8 3.7c-3.9 3.1-11.4 4.2-15.9 2-1.7-1-3.1-2.4-4.6-3.7-2.2-1.9-4.5-3.9-6.3-6.2-1.2-1.5-2.7-3-3.6-4.7-2.6-4.9-2.5-9.5-2-14.8.4-4.8 4.2-9.1 9-9.6 1.6-.2 3.2-.5 4.7-.7 1.4-.1 2.8-.2 4.1-.7 3.9-1.8 7.7-4 12-4.4 2.4-.3 4.8 1 6.2 2.8.7 1.2 1 2.4 1.8 3.5.5.8 1 1.7 1.7 2.3 1.4 1 3 1.8 4.4 2.6 4.1 2.3 10.9 4 11.6 9.5.4 4.2-3.1 7.6-6 10.1-2.9 2.5-6.5 3.5-9.8 5z" fill="#ffff9f" />
    <path d="M115 302.4c0-3.3 3.7-5.5 6.6-4 3.3 1.5 3.3 6.4 0 8-3 1.5-6.6-.8-6.5-4zM55 245c0 3.4.1 6.9-.7 10.2-.6 2-1 4.2-2 6l-.2.2-.2.2c-2.7 1-5.9 1-8.8 1.4-4.8.5-9.7 1-14.5 1.7-2.7.5-5.7.8-7.9 2.7-.8.6-1.2 1.5-1.8 2.3l-.1 0-.1 0-.1 0-.2 0c-1-1.2-1.4-2.7-2.1-4-.8-1.6-1.8-3.1-2.6-4.7-1-2.5-1-5.3-1.7-7.9 14.4-1.9 28.7-5.3 43-8zm49.4-11.6c.1 3.5.4 6.9.7 10.3-9.4.4-15 .8-23.4-4.5-.3-3.5-1.2-7-1.6-10.5-.2-2-.8-4.6 1-6.1 4.1-3.4 10.4-1.8 14.6.4 4.6 2 7 6 8.7 10.4zM79 322.8c-3 .6-6 1-9 1.5-1.2.1-2.3.5-3.5.5l-.1-.1c-.4-1-.2-2-.1-3 .2-1.9 1.7-3.4 3.2-4.3 3.4-1.7 7.7-2.3 11.3-1.2 1.5.5 3.2 1.1 4 2.5.3 1 0 2-.2 3-1.8.5-3.8.7-5.6 1zm130.6-13.2c-5.7-1-11.4-1.7-17-3-9.8-2.4-19.4-5.7-28-11 1.6-1 3.2-1.8 5-1.9 3.8-.1 7.5.6 11.2 1 10.8 1.3 21.7 2 32.6 3 15.5 1.3 31.2.7 46.7-1 8.6-1.1 13.1-.1 16.2 8.7a52 52 0 012.3 10c.5 3 .2 6-1.2 8.7-4.2-1-8.4-2.2-12.3-4.1-3-1.5-5.6-3.5-8.6-4.9a27.8 27.8 0 00-10.3-2.6c-5.8-.4-11.7-.2-17.5-.6-6.4-.3-12.8-1.2-19.1-2.3z" fill="#b58254" />
    <path d="M1205 223.9c-13.5-.9-32.7-3.6-46-1.3-18 3.7-37.4 9-54.2 16.5-4.6 2.4-11.4 7.4-15.6 10.6-9.1 6.3-20.6 13-30.5 17.9-15.9 8-35.8 17.6-51.8 25.2-5.7 2.4-12.4 4.3-18.6 4.6-13.7 1-31-1.2-44.8.5-14.2 2.3-29 7.1-42.4 12.3-6.6 2.5-24 11.5-30.8 13.7-5.7 1.3-12.6 1.8-18.4.4-11-4.9-24.9-12-36.4-15.5-18.7-5.3-39.6-8.6-59-6-17.6 2.5-37 11.8-53.6 18-11.3 4.6-25.2 11.9-37.6 12.3-20.2 1.9-43.5-2.2-63.7-3.4-8 0-31.6 2.2-40 2.9-13 1.2-26.1-3.2-37.8-8.5-6.2-2.6-13-7.9-19.8-9-45.4 4.9-93.3-8.4-138.7-2.7l-3.5 1.3c-4.8 2.2-9.5 7-13.2 10.7-3.6 3.3-9.5 7.2-13.7 9.9-17.7-3.5-50.6-7.1-67.2-13.2-17.7-9.8-16.7-8.6-36.9-9-27.9-2.6-60.2-6.2-80-28.2-18.4-19.9-27.4-54-21.2-80.4-15.2-2-123.3 18.7-140.7 21.4l23.4 125.6c51.4-9.2 112.6-22 164.9-20.5 20.8 5.6 47 6.4 68.4 9 35.4 7.2 80.9 16.5 116 25.5l.7-24.7-2.4-3.3-1-2.2-.2-1.3c0-.9.1-2.5.3-3.3l.4-1.4 1-1.6 1.4-1.3c5.2-3.6 11.9-5.3 18.2-5.6 39.7-1.5 82 7 121.8 3.5l2 .4c34.4 17.4 42.2 19 80.6 15.1 23.9-2 49.4 3.5 73.4 2.5 10.2-.2 21.6-2.2 31-6.2 38.5-15.2 68.3-32.2 111.2-22.4 20.2 3.3 38.2 19.2 58.8 20.3 17.8 1.2 34.5-12 50.8-17.3 12.2-4.3 27.2-9.4 40.2-10.2 12.1-.3 28.6 1.4 40.6-.5 23.7-3.3 54.6-22.7 76.2-32.4 15-7.2 34.4-22.4 49.6-29.2 16.2-6.3 34.2-11.5 51.6-13.6 16.8 0 37.3 2.5 54.1 2.6l6.4-7.6-23.3-1zM84.6 321.8c-3.5.7-13.9 2.4-17.6 3l-.5-.2-.2-.9 0-1.7.4-1.5.7-1.2 1.3-1.3 1.3-.8 1.7-.7c1-.4 3.5-.7 4.6-.8l2.7 0 2.6.7 2.3 1.2.6.5.4.6 0 1.1-.3 2zm48.6-14.5l-1 2.2-1.4 1.8-1.7 1.4-2 1c-1.5.6-26.6 4.4-29 4.8l-.9-.1-.8-.6c-1.3-1.4-6-6.8-7.5-7.8l-2-1.3-2.2-1-2.3-.5-5.8-.6-1.2-8-3.8.4 1.1 8-3.2.7-3.2 1.5-2.7 1.8-2.8 2.7-1.6 2.3-1.3 2.5-1.4 4-.7 4.3-.4.4-.4.2c-5.9 1.2-13.4 2.6-19.4 2.4l-3.3-.7-3-1.1-2.6-1.5-2.4-2-1.5-1.7-1.4-2c-1.4-2.9-2.4-7.2-3-10.2-2.1-14.2-11-55.7-13.8-70.2l0-1 1.2-.3 2.2-.3 2.2 13.6.4.6.5.2c16.8-2 53-9.9 70-13.3l.4-.4.1-.9c-.4-2.9-2-11-1.7-13.9l.3-1 .8-1 1.3-1 1.4-.5 1.7-.4c5.1-.4 10.5 1.8 14.4 5.2.6.6 1.7 2 2.1 2.7l2.3 4.8c.5 11.6 2.5 24.7 7.4 35.2 4.2 11.6 11.8 21.8 20.5 30.3l.7 2 .6 2.9 0 2-.2 1.4z" fill="#b4b4b4" stroke-opacity=".5" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".3" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: awesome, I will give it a go tonigth

Comment: ``svg.querySelectorAll('*:not([fill="' + filterColor + '"])');`` should give you all elements you want to remove

Comment: @Danny '365CSI' Engelman: you're right! Your approach is more straight forward. But you might also accidentally strip elements within the `<defs>` that are still needed for remaining nodes.